# Avoid if for chained objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, if-statement

I have one complex object just like this;

```
Object A
   Object B
    Object C
      Object D
        property A
        property B
```

So If I need to show the property A in my view, I need to

```
  A.getB().getC().getD().getPropertyA();
```

but what if my user doesn`t send the object C?

so I need to create one If for every object

```
if(A.getB() != null){
  if(A.getB().getC() != null){
    if(A.getB().getC().getD() != null){
      //here I can show the propertyA
    }
  } 
}
```

now I have to show this property in 3 views

There is a better way to does this? a framework or something like this to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Optional.ofNullable` and `map`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(A.GetB())
    .map(B::getC)
    .map(C::getD)
    .map(D::getPropertyA)
    .orElseThrow()
```

P.S.1: Some developers (and linters) find this approach a code smell, but I think it's more readable that way.

P.S.2: You can use a default value with `.orElse` instead of `.orElseThrow`.

Comment: I think this is actually one case where it works pretty well, I just don't like when people pass a default value and do this when they have a local variable already. and can just use a ternary expression

Comment: This approach solve all the levels of my problem? if I have null in my getD or getC? tks

Comment: @FabioEbner correct. Consider upvoting / marking as correct if it helped.

Comment: Only one more doubt, and if I have one of this subobjects are a List? sample List< ObjectC>

Comment: @FabioEbner then what?